# Microsoft Access Website on IIS server 2012 R2

Tags: ms-access, iis

I have heard that you can create database websites using Microsoft access and was wondering if it's possible to host these on a local IIS server for an intranet page or is it set up only to work with sharepoint? If its possible ny advice or information you can give on how to set it up would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This walkthrough covers setting up in local IIS

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/445z2s49(v=vs.100).aspx

It is stand-alone, although if you need to embedded in SharePoint iframes can be allowed.